# Find proportions of two variable which are not positive

Tags: probability, linear-transformations

Assume I have two variables $x$ and $y$ where both of these are representations of scores and each has a range of $-1$ to $1$. Is it possible to somehow map $x$ and $y$ such that they both represent proportions. If it is not possible why is it not possible? What property is abandoned? This generalises to the idea that if we have two variables with infinite range ($-\infty$,$\infty$) can they be mapped to a proportion?

Comment: It depends on your objective. What kind of "proportions" you want? There are many functions map into the $[0, 1]$ interval like $\sin$, or any CDF etc. So are those functions generate the "proportion" you want?

Comment: @BGM the reason i used the proportion is. For example, (x,y) is a coordinate on euclidean real space. I want to map (x,y) to become a proportion eg f (x,y)=(0.2,0.8). This is a proportion because it sums to 1.

Comment: So you want something like $\displaystyle \left(\frac {x+1} {x+y+2}, \frac {y+1} {x+y+2}\right)$ in your example?

Comment: @BGM Indeed that is very good. Is there a way map from the entire real space instead. ie x is on the entire real line and y is on the entire real line

Comment: There are many maps can achieve this. I have not think of any sophisticated one, maybe you can try $\displaystyle \left( \frac {F(x)} {F(x) + (y)},  \frac {G(y)} {F(x) + (y)}\right)$ where $F, G$ are CDFs respectively. To avoid the denominator equals to zero, you just need to require the support of $F, G$ to be the entire real line, say normal distribution. So one obvious way to do this is to use some function to map them to bounded interval and then take the proportion like that. You can also assign weights, etc.